# updating values in a Generic list by comparing with another list (different class)

Tags: c#, list, generics, for-loop, collections

I have a generic list LIST AList that has already been populated, from the database.
I have another generic list List BList which is populated by reading a flat file.
I am trying to compare the two lists based on some field

Update , am using the following basic for loop :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < AList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (AList[i].Someval== BList[i].Someval)
                {
                    AList[i].Value1 = BList[i].SomeValue;
                    -----
                }
            }
```

With this loop all the values of the field in all rows in the list are getting updated , and not the value of the index.

Comment: The most efficient way depends on if you need to actually call the properties of AList items in order to set them, or if have a predefined type in AList, or if anonymous types are ok.

Comment: 1 - So, do you WANT that ALL values get updated?
2 - Do you want to do that only for items with same index in the A and B lists?
3 - If you want to update ALL items in A that has someval == an item in B, what if BList have two items with same Someval?

Comment: @Daniel
1) No I only want to update only values in the row.
2) Yes 
3) Blist will never have more values that AList .I don't want to update all values.

Comment: But your loop IS doing what you want....

Comment: @Daniel It is not . It is not updating any row at all. When I am iterating , it does add the value to the row, but that value does not get saved and goes back to null when I get out of the loop

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.0 you can do this:

```
var listA = GetGenericListA();
var listB = GetGenericListB();

var listAandB = listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => new {a, b} );

foreach (var item in listAandB)
{
    if (item.a.Somefield == item.b.SomeFieldb)
    {
        item.a.firstData = item.b.someData;
        item.a.secondData = item.b.someotherField;
    }
}
```

It might be not the fastest way, but it is quite fast and it is easy to read / maintain.

Comment: ,is there a way to break the again after the update is complete